# jQuery change() not recognized by css

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, onchange

I'm building an off-canvas navigation with a little bit of jQuery help.

The Navigation itself is triggered via a checkbox `.menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul`.

On a change event of the checkbox I toggle classes, which works nice. But now I want to fire these changes also when a navigation Item is clicked, so that the navigation collapses on click automatically. Everything works fine so far, but when I trigger the `change()` on the navigation click, the `.menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul` are still applied, instead of the default styles. Do you have any idea why this is so?

The toggleClasses in the `$('#NavButton').change()` function are executed on a navigation link click and the css reacts to it, it's just that the `.menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul` is still applied.

Since the toggleClasses are fired, I assume that the checkbox state is changed (unfortunately I can't see the checkbox state in FireBug, if anybody knows how to do this, let me know!), that's why I'm stumped why the `.menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul` is still applied.

Here is the code

CSS:

```
.menu > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    border-color: #111111;
    @include box-shadow (none);
    background-image: none;
    background: #3B3B3B;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: width 0.3s ease;
}
.menu input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ ul {
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -20%;
} 
.wrapper.open {
    left: 20%;    
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
body.open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#NavButton').change(function() {
            $('.wrapper').toggleClass('open');
            $('body').toggleClass('open');
            $('#PrimNav a').toggleClass('open');
        });
$('#PrimNav').on('click', '.open', function() {
    console.log('change'); //<- Is working!
    $('#NavButton').change(); //<- Is working!
});
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="menu" aria-labelledby="mainnav-desc" role="navigation">
    <input id="NavButton" type="checkbox">
    <label for="NavButton">Menu</label>
    <ul id="PrimNav" class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Example Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#NavButton').change()` does not uncheck the box. You should do so explicitly:

```
$('#NavButton').prop('checked',false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/kxSqW/

Comment: Thank you! I thought `change()` would uncheck it. My bad! Now its working. :)